# How to prevent apify auto-sorting results?

Tags: node.js, sorting, apify

Apify recently started to auto-sort results alphabetically. Its really annoying when we are uploading results directly to database.

Original column order given inside the code:

```
Result1
Result2
.
.
.
Result10
Result11
.
.
.
Result20
```

After Apify sorts it alphabetically:

```
Result1
Result10
Result11
.
.
.
Result2
Result20
.
.
.
Result3
Result4
.
.
.
Result9
```

Is there anyway we can prevent this and retain the original column order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has always been like that for tabulated formats. You can add your own sorting if you add the `fields` parameter to the dataset items URL. Like this

https://api.apify.com/v2/datasets/DATASET_ID/items?clean=true&format=csv&fields=Result1,Result2

As the question was also about the [Google Sheets](https://apify.com/lukaskrivka/google-sheets) actor, here is a solution for that:

1. The Google Sheets actor has a column order field
2. It also has a checkbox to retain the column order of the original sheet

Comment: But, when I directly upload to googlesheet or database and there are 100s of fields, would this method work?

Comment: You do you mean by "directly"? All datasets are uploaded via this API URL so if you can amend it, you can order it

Comment: I meant if we are using a webhook and your googlesheet actor, we will be providing only the dataset id. And if we are to update the webhook url, wouldnt it be like typing out the entire column list? No other option available?

Comment: Also webhook will be having the googlesheet actor task id, adding the column list there, will it work? I am really confused.

Comment: You actually have 2 options:
1. The Google Sheets actor has a column order field
2. It also has a chebox to retain column order of the original sheet

Comment: Ok, didnt notice that before, will try that out. Can you please update this to your answer, so, I can mark it as the answer.